What happens to a goroutine when context timeouts
I have the following code:
func example() int {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), time.Second*2)
    defer cancel()
    ch := make(chan int)

    go func() {
        defer fmt.Println("Goroutine exiting")
        time.Sleep(time.Second * 3)
        ch <- 0

        for {
            fmt.Println("I am still alive!")
            time.Sleep(time.Second * 1)
        }
    }()

    select {
    case <-ch:
        return 0
    case <-ctx.Done():
        return 1
    }
}

func main() {
    r := example()
    fmt.Println(r)
    time.Sleep(time.Second * 10)
}

Here is a brief description:

The example func:

creates a context with a timeout of 2 seconds
runs a goroutine that sleeps for 3 seconds and writes 0 to the channel. After that, it infinitely starts to print "I am still alive!" every second
waits either on the result from the goroutine or context.Done


The main func

calls the example func
prints the result
sleeps for 10 seconds



My question is: what happens to the goroutine when the example function exits?
I don't see either "Goroutine exiting" or "I am still alive!" messages.
So my conclusion is that the goroutine is blocked on the "ch <- 0" line.
Does not it mean that such code will generate a lot of goroutines that will never exit and will use resources?

The goroutine is blocked on the statement ch <- 0.  The goroutine never exits and uses resources until the program exits.  To fix, replace ch <- 0 with close(ch) or make ch a buffered channel.

@CeriseLimón, so the problem with my dummy example is that when the example function ends, there are no listeners on ch, so ch <- 0 blocks forever...

The statement ch <- 0 blocks forever in that scenario because ch is an unbuffered channel and there is not a goroutine that receives on ch.

@CeriseLimón, thank you for your help!
